# Extbase TYPO3 - Expand query with custom WHERE parts

Tags: mysql, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a model ("offers") that has the attributes lat/lng among many other meta attributes. Inside a repository method I am able to fetch offers according to matching metadata like:

```
$where[] = $query->equals('special', 1);
$where[] = $query->equals('region', 7);
$where[] = $query->greaterThan('crdate', $minTime);
```

Now I need to be able to to a radius search depending on the lat/lng attributes. In a usual SQL query this would be something like:

```
WHERE acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(lat)) + cos(:lat)*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-:lng)) * :R < :rad
```

However since this contains mathematic values, I don't see a possibility to add a $query counterpart. How cann I pass a WHERE portion like this to an extbase query?

What I would like to avoid:

- Using a raw admin_query() with $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB'] with all the same $where conditions that I gathered before the execute() method of the proper Query, to gather the UIDs of the available records, and append the $query with a condition that only returns those matching the UID of the second query
- Rewriting the whole repository method to use a raw sql method and iterate that to generate the propery ER-Model of Extbase.

So ideally, I'd like to have something like:

```
$query->customSQL('blablabla > bla');
```

which would get appended to the SQL WHERE part later on. Maybe I could first create a placeholder like

```
$query->equals('placeholder', 1);
```

and then somehow get the statement before execution, do a

str_replace('placeholder = 1', '...my real radius statement...')

But I only see a getStatement() not a setStatement() in the QueryInterface...

Answer (score 0):

The function you were looking for is called `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query()`, it‘s not defined in the interface. You‘ll have to write the whole query by yourself - it‘s not possible to mix extbase query builder and plain SQL code here.

You can (and should) use prepared queries (`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\PreparedStatement`) here, though.

I did something similar in a project and paste my code below, maybe it helps you:

```
/**
 * Creates a prepared statement
 *
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\PreparedStatement
 */
protected function getPreparedStatement()
{
    if (is_null($this->statement)) {
        $this->statement = $this->getDatabaseConnection()->prepare_SELECTquery(
            '*, ( :meanradius * acos(LEAST(1, cos( radians( :latitude ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) )' .
            ' * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( :longitude ) )' .
            ' + sin( radians( :latitude ) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )' .
            ' ) AS distance',
            $this->tableName,
            'HAVING distance < :radius',
            '',
            'distance',
            ':limit '
        );
    }
    return $this->statement;
}
```

and later, in my `find*` method:

```
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $statement = $this->getPreparedStatement();
    $statement->bindValues([
        ':meanradius' => CoordinateInterface::EARTH_MEAN_RADIUS,
        ':latitude' => $latitude,
        ':longitude' => $longitude,
        ':radius' => $radius,
        ':limit' => $limit,
    ]);
    $query->statement(($statement));
    return $query->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for your imput. I wish I could somehow get the current statement before executing the query, and then just adding one more WHERE clause.

However, I now populate an extra array of WHERE clauses for my find method and pass that along to building the custom SQL statement. It's redundant, but if there's no other way, I'll go that route.

I first thought I might be able to inject my WHERE parts in the storagepageUid() clause, but couldn't pass strings in there.